# Ветки на сообщение бота и реакции discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы в определенном канале бот удалял сообщение, потом создавал эмбет и переписывал сообщение в эмбет, так же создавал ветку и ставил реакции на свой эмбет?

Кода немного есть, но это в основном переписывание сообщения от участника(так и нужно), и удаление оригинального сообщения(от участника конечно же)

````
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author != bot.user:
        await ctx.reply(ctx.content)
        await ctx.delete()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получаем канал методом `client.get_channel`:

```
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author != bot.user:
        channel = client.get_channel(id)
```

Проверяем с какого канала пришло сообщение:

```
        if channel.id == ctx.channel.id:
```

Если это нужный нам канал:

1. Удаляем сообщение.

```
            await ctx.delete()
```

2. Создаём `embed` и отправляем сообщение.

```
            embed = discord.Embed(title="New message:", description=ctx.content)
            message = await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

3. Добавляем к отправленному сообщению реакцию.

```
            await message.add_reaction('')
```

Полный код:

```
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author != bot.user:
        channel = client.get_channel(id)
        if channel.id == ctx.channel.id:
            await ctx.delete()
            embed = discord.Embed(title="New message:", description=ctx.content)
            message = await channel.send(embed=embed)
            await message.add_reaction('')
```

Comment: ***Если я Вам помог, отметьте этот ответ галочкой и полезным.***

Comment: А какие библиотеки нужны? Ато у меня такая ошибка line 17, in on_message
    channel = client.get_channel(1070981037980655646)
              ^^^^^^
NameError: name 'client' is not defined

Comment: Измените ***client*** на то ***что используете*** при создании команд: 
@`...`.command()

Библиотек никаких не нужно.

Comment: Прости, что так долго не отвечал. Сработало. Кстати, ты не полностью дописал код, а именно в строке с созданием эмбета ```description=ctx.content```, но это ты сделал на лучше, чтобы мне пришлось догадаться что нужно поставить. Спасибо чувак, ты крут! И да, лови галочку.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Это базовый материал, поэтому я думал, что ты уже в курсе. Удачи.

Comment: Ещё раз привет. Оказалась проблема, что с этим кодом ниодна команда не работает. await bot.process_commands(message) пробывал.

Comment: В `await bot.process_commands(message)` измените `message` на `ctx`.